# How to reveal this image after some text is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use this animation but I need that if some text is clicked then the image should be revealed.
Could you please help me as I am a beginner.
Thanks.
[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/gabrielcojea/pen/wvKjMPw)

```
let revealBox = document.querySelector('.reveal-box');

let animate = function() {
    if (revealBox.classList.contains('enter')) {
        revealBox.classList.remove('enter');
        revealBox.classList.add('leave');
    } else {
        revealBox.classList.remove('leave');
        revealBox.classList.add('enter');
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', animate);
```

Comment: that's the thing to modify : `document.body.addEventListener('click', animate);` to set the onclick  elsewhere than body. You can use document.querySelector(' myCssSelector') ; possible example to let you see the idea :https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYyREYj

Comment: @G-Cyrillus thanks a lot but i wanted that it should not show on start and when clicked it should show. i tried to remove classes but it didn't work. Please help.!

Comment: reload and see the switch of enter/leave class inside the HTML .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus great. but why it animate the first time?

Comment: because it has a duration of .9s, you can set a negative delay to go over it : pen updated ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus thanks it works now. Please answer the same as i want to give you the credit answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he is a possible upodate from the code that seems to work like you expect :

The idea is to switch the initial className used to hide/show the img at first : `class="reveal-box enter  animate"` becomes  `class="reveal-box leave animate"`

To avoid waiting the 0.9s duration time that takes to hide the img, you can add a négative delay equal or superior to the duration value. This negative delay should be fired only on load and then be reset to 0.

It can be added via a class by a custom `delay`removed on the first click via `revealBox.classList.remove('delay');`.

Once class `enter` and `leave` are switched in the HTML and the `delay` class added to the HTML **and created in the  CSS**, the `img` should not be seen untill the first click.

example:

```js
let revealBox = document.querySelector('.reveal-box');

let animate = function() {
  if (revealBox.classList.contains('enter')) {
    revealBox.classList.remove('enter');
    revealBox.classList.add('leave');
  } else {
    revealBox.classList.remove('leave');
    revealBox.classList.remove('delay');
    revealBox.classList.add('enter');
  }
}

document.querySelector('.reveal-box p').addEventListener('click', animate);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px;
}

.reveal-box {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  max-height: 480px;
  width: calc((100vh - 48px) * 0.66);
  max-width: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.reveal-box__inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.reveal-box__inner::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #c1b294;
}

.reveal-box__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.enter .reveal-box__inner {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0s both paused slide-in-right;
}

.enter .reveal-box__inner::after {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0.6s both paused slide-out-right;
}

.enter .reveal-box__image {
  animation: 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0.3s both paused scale-in-down;
}

.leave .reveal-box__inner {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0s both paused slide-out-right;
}

.leave .reveal-box__inner::after {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0s both paused slide-in-left;
}

.leave .reveal-box__image {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0s both paused slide-out-left;
}

.leave.delay .reveal-box__inner {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) -1s both paused slide-out-right;
}

.leave.delay .reveal-box__inner::after {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) -1s both paused slide-in-left;
}

.leave.delay .reveal-box__image {
  animation: 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0s both paused slide-out-left;
}

.animate .reveal-box__inner {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.animate .reveal-box__inner::after {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.animate .reveal-box__image {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes slide-in-right {
  0% {
    transform: translate3D(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out-right {
  0% {
    transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3D(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-left {
  0% {
    transform: translate3D(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out-left {
  0% {
    transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3D(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes scale-in-down {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="reveal-box leave delay  animate">
  <p>Some text to click</p>
  <div class="reveal-box__inner">
    <img class="reveal-box__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575626465329-3704c434a524?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1268&q=80">
  </div>
</div>
```

forked codepen : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYyREYj to play with.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap any text in a `<span>` tag. And give it an id or class.

```
<span id="click-to-reveal">Some text</span>
```

You can select it in the script:

```
const text = document.getElementById("click-to-reveal");
```

And add the eventlistener to it instead:

```
text.addEventListener('click', animate);
```

Comment: he also needs need to switch the class enter/leave (inside HTML) if it is to be hidden at first ;)